# Nginx location block for two url patterns

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to use nginx proxy_pass to reverse proxy a web application for me. Informally, I am trying to do the following:

```
http://localhost/abc/$1 --> http://localhost:8080/$1
```

Except for the special case where `$1` is empty, in which case I want to:

```
http://localhost/abc --> http://localhost:8080/def
```

I notice I can do the former with this:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location /abc/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
    }
}
```

and the latter with this:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location /abc/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/def;
    }
}
```

But I can't seem to combine them to do what I want.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I was able to do it with an extra location block:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location = /abc/ {
        return 302 /abc/def;
    }

    location /abc/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
    }
}
```